# How to create a list of directories with variable names assigned to it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
Folder1 = "images" # Just assigns name to the folder
Folder2 = "images2"
Folder3 = "images2"

def main(argv=None):
            if not gfile.Exists(Folder1):
                gfile.MakeDirs(Folder1)
            if not gfile.Exists(Folder2):
                gfile.MakeDirs(Folder2)
            if not gfile.Exists(Folder2):
                gfile.MakeDirs(Folder2)

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            tf.app.run()
```

Is there a better way to create these directories using dictionaries and assigning the folder names to a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can store your folder names in a list, and use a `for`-loop to create each folder:

```
folders = ["images", "images2", "images2"]

def main(argv=None):
    for folder in folders:
        if not gfile.Exists(folder):
            gfile.MakeDirs(folder)
```

If you prefer to access each folder by a specific name, you can use a dictionary:

```
folders = {'Folder1': "image1", 'Folder2': "image2", 'Folder3': "image2"}

def main(argv=None):
    for folder in folders.values():
        if not gfile.Exists(folder):
            gfile.MakeDirs(folder)
```

Comment: I need to access them later which would end me up with this
`var = access(main.folders[0])`

Could the `main.folder[0]` be accessed as a variable? Dicts would be better

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want with dictionaires (as you asked)

```
def create_folders(**kwargs):
print(kwargs)
for fName in kwargs:
    print(kwargs[fName])
    if not gfile.Exists(kwargs[fName]):
       gfile.MakeDirs(kwargs[fName])

create_folders(Folder1="images",Folder2="images2",Folder3="images2")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you use a dictionary like this:

```
folders = dict()
folders['Folder1'] = 'images'
for i in range(2, 4):
  folders['Folder' + str(i)] = 'images' + str(i)

def main(argv=None):
  for k, v in folders:
    if not gfile.Exists(v):
      gfile.MakeDirs(v)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

The first loop is to create the dictionary dynamically.